# pandas Read undelimited text file to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to pandas. Up until now I've been learning pandas using csv files and excel spreadsheets.

Now I am faced with converting a text file to a dataframe. The text files is what I call sequential data. The format of the file is:

```
State Name
City Name
State Name
City Name
City Name
City Name
...
```

All 50 states plus US territories are listed but the number of cities varies. I need to convert this into a dataframe like

```
[[State Name, City Name1],[State Name, City Name2],...]
```

Using pandas read_table() method, I've been able to at least read the file into a dataframe, but now I'm not certain how to get it into the correct State Name City Name format.

I also have a dictionary of State Name/State 2 letter abbreviations available. The format of the dictionary is

```
{'OH':'OHIO', 'KY':'Kentucky',...}
```

Is there a way I can use this dictionary, loop over the file and separate the state and city? or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Thank you

**EDIT - Sample of Text File**
A sample of the text file is listed below. Also, please not that I am unable to alter the file.

```
Alabama[edit]  
Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
Florence (University of North Alabama) 
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2] 
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2] 
Troy (Troy University)[2] 
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4] 

Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5] 
Alaska[edit] 
Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2] 
Arizona[edit] 
Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6] 
Tempe (Arizona State University) 
Tucson (University of Arizona)
```

Comment: @ayhan. If anything the, the question you cited should be marked as a duplicate. This question was asked and answered before that one. Just saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your columns is called `A`. First find the states like this:

```
df.A.str.contains('\[edit\]')
Out[25]: 
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10    False
11     True
12    False
13    False
14    False
```

Use `cumsum` to define an index per state+cities:

```
csum = df.A.str.contains('\[edit\]').cumsum()
csum
Out[26]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     2
10    2
11    3
12    3
13    3
14    3
```

Now you can get States and Cities:

```
states = df.groupby(csum).first()
states
Out[38]: 
                 A
A                 
1  Alabama[edit]  
2    Alaska[edit] 
3   Arizona[edit] 

cities = df.groupby(csum).apply(lambda g: g[1:])
cities
Out[39]: 
                                                      A
A                                                      
1 1                       Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
  2             Florence (University of North Alabama) 
  3     Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
  4         Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2] 
  5           Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2] 
  6                          Troy (Troy University)[2] 
  7   Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman Co...
  8                  Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5] 
2 10     Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2] 
3 12        Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6] 
  13                  Tempe (Arizona State University) 
  14                     Tucson (University of Arizona)
```

Now join the dataframes:

```
states.join(cities, rsuffix='_cities')
Out[49]: 
                    A                                           A_cities
A                                                                       
1 1   Alabama[edit]                        Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
  2   Alabama[edit]              Florence (University of North Alabama) 
  3   Alabama[edit]      Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
  4   Alabama[edit]          Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2] 
  5   Alabama[edit]            Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2] 
  6   Alabama[edit]                           Troy (Troy University)[2] 
  7   Alabama[edit]    Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman Co...
  8   Alabama[edit]                   Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5] 
2 10    Alaska[edit]      Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2] 
3 12   Arizona[edit]         Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6] 
  13   Arizona[edit]                   Tempe (Arizona State University) 
  14   Arizona[edit]                      Tucson (University of Arizona)
```

Comment: this is a great answer. This helped me out when I found that there is a city named California in Pennsylvania.

Comment: @PaulStoner you're very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I would create a `cities` list populated with `(state_name, city_name)` tuples, and then turn this list of tuples into a `DataFrame`.

For that you'll need a precompiled list of all the states that appear in your text file, so that we can identify when the file cursor is on a state line or on a city line.

```
cities = []
list_of_states = ['Alaska', ..., 'Ohio', ...]

with open('file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line in list_of_states:
            state = line
        else:
            cities.append((state, line))

df = pandas.DataFrame(cities)
```

Comment: @Javin That will work. Thanks for the assist

Comment: @Javin I am sincerely apologetic for changing the accepted answer on you. Your is a perfectly acceptable answer and very easily implemented. In fact, it was your answer that led me yo find a city with the same name as a state.

Comment: @PaulStoner no problem, I upvoted the now-accepted answer myself